# how to create apex master detail page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I Want to create apex master detail page on same page using oracle 18.2,
the master is form and detail interactive grid
when try to select master region for interactive grid the form not shown.
try to create the page manually even nothing shown for interactive grid master region

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Why reinventing the wheel? Use the Wizard:

- create page
- pick "master-detail" (not, report, not form, but *master-detail*)
- choose the layout (stacked is just fine)
- name the page (for example, "My master-detail form")
- fill in master region's info (title, columns, ...)
- do the same for detail region; if detail table has a foreign key to master table, the Wizard will recognize it

That's all; you'll get a master-detail page with two regions, both of them are interactive grids.

Comment: what if there is no foreign key to master table?  How to point it manually ?

Comment: I'd consider altering the table and adding the foreign key, @user3863616

Comment: seems resonable ;) until you can do it . Is it possible without foreign keys ?

Comment: I don't know, @user3863616, I never tried it **in Apex**. I did that in Oracle **Forms**, which lets you specify columns used to establish referential integrity. I guess it could be done in Apex as well, but how exactly ... can't tell. Probably by creating processes (automatic row fetching and such).